# Writing an Element object to file using java

Tags: java, data-structures, bloomberg

I have a data of Element class. I'm trying to write its values to a file but I'm having trouble:

```
< Some process to acquire values into the variable "fieldData" >

// Prepare file output
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/output.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

Element field = fieldData.getElement(i);

out.write(field);  // DOESN'T WORK: The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Element)
out.write(field.getValueAsString()); // DOESN'T WORK: Cannot convert SEQUENCE to String
```

Any suggestions on how I should handle this case? In addition, what is the best way for me to see (i.e. print out to screen) the available static variables and methods associated with an object? Thx.

More code snippets to help debug:

```
private static final Name SECURITY_DATA = new Name("securityData");
private static final Name FIELD_DATA = new Name("fieldData");

Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA); // msg is a Bloomberg desktop API object
Element securityData = securityDataArray.getValueAsElement(0);
Element fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA);
Element field = fieldData.getElement(0)
out.write(field);  // DOESN'T WORK: The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Element)
out.write(field.getValueAsString()); // DOESN'T WORK: Cannot convert SEQUENCE to String
```

Comment: What is the return type of the "getValueAsString" method ? It seams that this return is NOT a String but a SEQUENCE.

Comment: How do I check the "return type"?

Comment: Basically the `getValueAsString` method *doesn't* work on that `field` object(!) And the error code is what I showed in the comment. I tried to print `field.getClass()` and I get `com.bloomberglp.blpapi.impl.aB` Does that mean since it is a Bloomberg proprietary class, even though it is called Element, it doesn't behave like the generic Element class in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that this Bloomberg Prop data structure is long-winded to say the least:

```
private static final Name SECURITY_DATA = new Name("securityData");
private static final Name FIELD_DATA = new Name("fieldData");

Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA); // msg is a Bloomberg desktop API object
Element securityData = securityDataArray.getValueAsElement(0);
Element fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA);
Element field = fieldData.getElement(0); 

/* the above codes were known at the time of the question */
/* below is what I was shown by a bloomberg representative */

Element bulkElement = field.getValueAsElement(0);
Element elem = bulkElement.getElement(0);
out.write(elem.name() + "\t" + elem.getValueAsString() + "\n");
```

whew...I don't think they try to make it easy! I'm also curious as to if there was a way that I could have figure this out by having Java print out the right method to use to trace down the data structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Element element = msg.GetElement("securityData");
 for (int i = 0; i < element.NumValues; i++)
 {

  Element security = element.GetValueAsElement(i);  //ie: DJI INDEX
  Element fields = security.GetElement("fieldData");//ie: INDX_MEMBERS

  for (int j = 0; j < fields.NumElements; j++) 
  {
   Element field = fields.GetElement(j); //a list of members

   for (int k = 0; k < field.NumValues; k++)
   {
       //print field.GetValueAsElement(k); //print members name              
   } 
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to print the value of a input field element?

If so, then try:

```
out.write(field.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Tried. It says `The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Element`...

Comment: is the Element object you're using org.w3c.dom.Element?

Comment: Really have no idea. Just added some more code snippets for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one, for your second question:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html